# Possible DNS issue when using yum: "Could not resolve host: (every mirror); Unknown error" Centos 7

Tags: domain-name-system, centos7, yum

Some specifications and background information:
Running Centos Linux release 7.2.1511 (core), Static IP address,
Dedicated server machine not configured by me, also I have very little linux experience.

I am trying to set up the server to host a tomcat web application that uses a MySQL database. However whenever I try to install the required software I get a "Could not resolve host error". I have tried multiple suggestions and the solutions in a previous similar question: [Could not resolve host](https://serverfault.com/questions/904304/could-not-resolve-host-mirrorlist-centos-org-centos-7). However none seem to work.

I can successfully ping my local host 127.0.0.1, but not googles public nameserver 8.8.8.8. When I try ping 8.8.8.8 and the public-gateway address there is 100% packet loss. Which in the previous question's answer indicates the local network configuration is wrong and you'll have to check the configuration. Below is the local network configuration:

**Network information**

```
[xxxx]$ nmcli d
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
enp3s0  ethernet  connected  enp3s0
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --

[xxxx]$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
```

My `etc/resolv.conf` file contains

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

`host google.com` simply results in: `-bash: host: command not found` This is also the case with the nslookup and dig commands.

**Output:**

```
[xxxx]$ sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
http://ca.mirror.babylon.network/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: ca.mirror.babylon.network; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.netaddicted.ca/CentOS/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirror.netaddicted.ca; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.
etc...
```

**firewall-cmd --list-all**

```
[xxxx]$ firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: enp3s0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 10000/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

**google's public nameserver ping failure**

```
[xxxx]$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6999ms
```

**Local gateway ping failure**

```
[xxxx]$ ping xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
...
11 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9999ms
```

**Further specification and update:** The server is connected to a larger network managed by an IT department. I am currently contacting one of the IT employees to ensure the firewall is open for this server.

I hope this is relevant and useful information. Thanks in advance for you time. I will update the question once I know if the problem was on the IT staff side and the firewall configuration.

**Final Update:**
This error was in fact due to the firewall configuration. Once the IT staff allowed access there was no longer any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your firewall is blocking the queries or responses:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
```

You can try to disable de firewall to check for sure if that's the cause:

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

If the firewall is the issue, you should allow the DNS service, allowing TCP/UDP traffic to/from the port 53.

Comment: Thanks, Leo I suspect it is a firewall issue and am going to contact the IT security department to ensure they are allowing the server access through the firewall while I update the system. The firewall-cmd --list-all command doesn't show anything being blocked so I suspect it is the firewall handled by the University staff which I will just have to wait for them to configure to allow the server access.

Comment: You are welcome. It might very well be that. I hope you solve it soon, if you do and found my answer helpful please accept it later. Regards