mirrorlist.centos.org no longer resolve?
mirrorlist.centos.org no longer online?
I can resolve to centos.org but not to mirrorlist.centos.org
Here is the output of my resolv.conf, dig, and nslookup if anyone interested.
rosdi@H-TQ0nmTkQIbRhN:~/test_ssl$ nslookup mirrorlist.centos.org
Server:         1.1.1.1
Address:        1.1.1.1#53

** server can't find mirrorlist.centos.org: NXDOMAIN

rosdi@H-TQ0nmTkQIbRhN:~/test_ssl$ nslookup centos.org
Server:         1.1.1.1
Address:        1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   centos.org
Address: 52.56.83.118
Name:   centos.org
Address: 81.171.33.201
Name:   centos.org
Address: 81.171.33.202
Name:   centos.org
Address: 2001:4de0:aaae::202
Name:   centos.org
Address: 2a05:d01c:c6a:cc02:225e:ab54:d58c:8b14
Name:   centos.org
Address: 2001:4de0:aaae::201

rosdi@H-TQ0nmTkQIbRhN:~/test_ssl$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8

rosdi@H-TQ0nmTkQIbRhN:~/test_ssl$ dig mirrorlist.centos.org

; <<>> DiG 9.18.24-0ubuntu5-Ubuntu <<>> mirrorlist.centos.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 61636
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mirrorlist.centos.org.         IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
centos.org.             2795    IN      SOA     ns1.centos.org. hostmaster.centos.org. 2024070102 28800 7200 2400000 3600

;; Query time: 70 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul 01 16:31:41 +08 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 101

rosdi@H-TQ0nmTkQIbRhN:~/test_ssl$ nslookup mirrorlist.centos.org
Server:         1.1.1.1
Address:        1.1.1.1#53

** server can't find mirrorlist.centos.org: NXDOMAIN

rosdi@H-TQ0nmTkQIbRhN:~/test_ssl$

mxtoolbox also showing the same thing.


I hate to be that-guy, but CentOS is EOL.  This is just another way of making people move to redhat and not hang about on old unsupported and increasingly vulnerable centos servers.   Onwards and Upwards !

Old question: https://serverfault.com/questions/904304/could-not-resolve-host-mirrorlist-centos-org-centos-7 / same question on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78692851/could-not-retrieve-mirrorlist-http-mirrorlist-centos-org-release-7arch-x86-6

@Criggie, I am building Ollama, they are using CentOS 7. According to the maintainer Nvidia driver support is better. I am sure they will move to newer distros shortly.

@rosdi: for some cases Nvidia driver support is very good on : fedora (the "closest" to centos? ...), or openSuse. (fwiw, in my own case (Asus laptop with "optimus" tech that makes difficult to use nvidia drivers) I had the best experience with Fedora (haven't tried openSuse yet, as Fedora + the support for optimus config worked for me)). Anything is better than using an EOL distribution (which will accumulate RCEs and other vulnerabilities)

Since you are using CentOS 7 I tried to add it in the title to attract more visitors. Also, I tried mentioning the last error message directly in the title. Thanks for this question.

@Criggie Meanwhile, we can still download Debian 3.0 Woody from 2002. I guess Red Hat is just having fears of being held responsible for distributing old software with known vulnerabilities, so, rm -Rf is their way of dealing with it.

mirrorlist.centos.org doesn't exists anymore.
From the .repo file:
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.

To resolve the issue you can mass update all .repo files:
sed -i s/mirror.centos.org/vault.centos.org/g /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*.repo
sed -i s/^#.*baseurl=http/baseurl=http/g /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*.repo
sed -i s/^mirrorlist=http/#mirrorlist=http/g /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*.repo


above 3 step is working properly, now yum running properly

I am using CentOS 7 to format my Hard drives from 520 bytes to 512 bytes. This worked out great for me. Thank you.

important caveat: bypassing that eol doesn't resolve the main issue: you'll be downloading outdated packages, probably containing more and more CVEs in them. This is not "to resolve the issue", but "to use your system until you find the proper solution"

@OlivierDulac Correct. I used the wrong word. This is a temporary workaround; correct resolution is to upgrade to newer distro.

@OlivierDulac Using outdated software with vulnerabilities is a choice that may even make sense in some context, so it does resolve the issue in that point of view :-)

Minor note - those sed commands are bash-specific. The second one won't work on some other shells, like fish. I got the error No matches for wildcard “s/^#.*baseurl=http/baseurl=http/g”. fish: sudo sed -i s/^#.*baseurl=http/baseurl=http/g /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*.repo

Centos 7 has reached EOL (End of Life) today, 1 July 2024, thus mirrorlist.centos.org is no longer required.
In order to install packages, you have to adjust repositories from "mirrorlist" to "baseurl". For most cases vault.centos.org will work well.

Great... :-D, I was struggling to build a docker image and as I got everything resolved... bam!... 1 July 2024....

important caveat: bypassing that eol by pointing to the vault: doesn't resolve the main issue: you'll be downloading (more and more-) outdated packages, probably containing more and more CVEs in them.

Try this :
sed -i 's|^mirrorlist=|#mirrorlist=|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*.repo
sed -i 's|^#\?baseurl=http://mirror\.centos\.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*.repo


I had to do a little bit different. As @mlazarov says, we need to update the repo files, but, instead of http, I changed to use https:
sed -i s/mirror.centos.org/vault.centos.org/g /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo
sed -i s/^#.*baseurl=http/baseurl=https/g /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo
sed -i s/^mirrorlist=http/#mirrorlist=https/g /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo

Running yum upgrade -y for example, I got:
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from base: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://vault.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 301 - Moved Permanently

The I added:
echo "sslverify=false" >> /etc/yum.conf

Update:
And it worked, but that breaks the reason for adding https :( so revert the sslverify hack and try this:
(For the impatient; Just paste the lines at the bottom and skip the waffle)
The issue here is that the Centos7 distribution Root and/or Intermediate Certificates are old and out of date. Some will have expired, some servers have moved and CAs may have come and gone.  We need to source a verifiably trusted source of a more recent ca-certificates package and download it over a means that ensures it's integrity.
We can get a more recent ca-certificates bundle from any of the 'historic/archive' mirrors, but they need to be trust worthy. Here is a short list.
https://mirror.nsc.liu.se/centos-store/
https://mirror.fcix.net/centos-vault/
https://archive.kernel.org/centos-vault/

Good, we can just use wget, and instal.. ah, humm, ok, problem, no wget, think again.  wget is missing, need yum to install it and that's broken have to find anyother way that will remove this deadlock.
Though there are ways to do a simple http GET from the shell on port 80, https (port 443) is more difficult. And getting ca-certificates without https would be insane. Of course you can use a memory stick, but I just found another way!
Luckily it seems a stock base install for Centos7 has urlgrabber, or at least the docker-hub container image centos:7 that I am using does.
The updated CA Certificates files we need can be fetched and installed with.
urlgrabber -o ca-certificates.rpm \
  http://archive.kernel.org/centos-vault/centos/7.9.2009/updates/Source/SPackages/ca-certificates-2023.2.60_v7.0.306-72.el7_9.src.rpm

rpm -i ca-certificates.rpm

# Then, AFTER applying the `sed` re-writes, above
# pull down all the updates

yum clean all && yum -y update



There's no point of using ssl if you are not verifying the ssl anyway, right?

Right. I can't explain too.

@Rosdi even unverified SSL(TLS) is still securely encrypted in transit, you just don't know whether you can trust the encrypter.

You can fix the cert error by downloading a newer ca-certs, but as yum is broken you will need to d/l an RPM and use rpm --setugid -i ca-certificates.rpm.   I've edited your answer to show this. as commends have too few letters an no formatting.

Yeah, changing http to https was required for it to work on our end.

Wouldn't it be more reasonable to disable the Centos-Base.repo, enable the Centos-Vault.repo, and add the corresponding configuration?
My system is CentOS 7.6.1810.
Configuration steps:
Disable all Centos-Base.repo repositories.
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

Add the following configuration to Centos-Vault.repo.
# Vault
[Vault-base]
name=Vault - CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-$releasever

[Vault-updates]
name=Vault - CentOS-$releasever - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-$releasever

[Vault-extras]
name=Vault - CentOS-$releasever - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-$releasever

Update the yum cache.
yum clean all ; yum makecache

Verification Results
[root@fab687ebbad7 yum.repos.d]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
repo id                                                                              repo name                                                                               status
!Vault-base/7/x86_64                                                                 Vault - CentOS-7 - Base                                                                 10,072
!Vault-extras/7/x86_64                                                               Vault - CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                  526
!Vault-updates/7/x86_64                                                              Vault - CentOS-7 - Updates                                                               6,173
repolist: 16,771


It's the same repo, it just changed URL, so updating the URL looks fine to me.
